# How to define and call a method with multiple parameters

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write a method/message with multiple parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066763/how-to-write-a-method-message-with-multiple-parameters)

I am really confused here... I have looked at SO and Google where I found an example of calling a method with two parameters.  So I modified it for my use, and unfortunately I can't get it to work.  Here is my updated code:

```
-  definition of method
- (NSArray *) fetchEventsBetweenDates: (NSDate *) sDate: andDate: (NSDate *) eDate;

- definitions and creation of sD and eD
    //  convert start dates to NSDate
    NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate* sD = [df dateFromString:@"10/03/2012"];
    NSLog(@"startDate: %@", sD);

    //  convert end dates to NSDate
    NSDate* eD = [df dateFromString:@"10/05/2012"];
    NSLog(@"endDate: %@", eD);

- call to method
    [self.eventsList addObjectsFromArray:[self fetchEventsBetweenDates: sD andDate: eD]];

- method
- (NSArray *) fetchEventsBetweenDates: (NSDate *) sDate: andDate: (NSDate *) eDate  {
```

I have tried every permutation I think was reasonable, and it still will not build.  I am getting a "expected ':' on the call to the method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The name of the method at definition and call are _completely_ different. Where does that "withEndDate:" part come from? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please read [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/&ei=kwZzUMjPLcv64QSUsIDgAw&usg=AFQjCNFR-4nUahyAELKcHUZDWKv3liXPEA&sig2=cMDkYKqua8zZwNcS8HcKYg) from Apple. Specifically the [Message Syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6) part.

The message declaration syntax is like this:

```
- (return type)myMethodParam1:(param1 type)p1 param2:(param2 type)p2;
```

Example:

```
- (NSArray *)fetchEventsBetweenDate:(NSDate *)startDate andDate:(NSDate *)endDate;
```

The implementation is the same, you just replace the semicolon `;` with the implementation in curly brackets `{ implementation }`.

When calling a method, you replace the parameter declarations with your variables:

```
// Assuming aDate and otherDate exist.
[self fetchEventsBetweenDate:aDate andDate:otherDate];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  That makes complete sense, once I have an example to look at.  I find the Apple Docs somewhat confusing, so this is what I needed.

However, I am getting a warning on the method call:  

Instance method '-fetchEventsBetweenDate:andDate:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

What is it talking about?

Comment: What object are you calling this message on? Paste what you're doing, otherwise I can't help

Comment: I updated the code to reflect what I have now... still getting the error in previous post...

Comment: Do you really comment like that? In Objective-C (and C) you comment with `//`, not with `-`.

Comment: I found it!  (misplaced colon)... thank you so much for the example...  and no, I don't comment like that... I've seen others do it that way when posting here, and I just assumed it was the norm.

Comment: Hmm, it's not `- (return type)myMethodParam1: param1:(param1 type)p1 param2:(param2 type)p2;` that's really confusing ... sigh

Comment: BTW the "Message Syntax" url is gone, 404-ed

Answer (score 5):

Start with a basic Objective-C book.   Pretty clear you don't understand the syntax or language yet (no big deal -- we all started there).

If you really had a method defined as:

```
- (NSArray *) fetchEventsForADay: (NSDate *) sDate: (NSDate *) eDate;
```

You would call it using `[someObj fetEventsForADay: date1 : date2];`   That would suck;  the whole point of Objective-C's interleave-arguments-with-method-name pattern is to make APIs self documenting.  Thus, you'd probably want:

- (NSArray *) fetchEventsBetweenStartDate:(NSDate*) sDate andEndDate:(NSDate*) eDate;

Which would be called like `[someObj fetchEventsBetweenStartDate: date1 andEndDate: date2];`.   Much clearer.